# this.setState() is not updating data immediately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

In my case setState() function doesn't work immediately. I am passing a data from child component to parent component, and on basis of returning data from child component I want to update text string in parent component.

here is my parent component:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      preview: "edit",
    }
  }
  toggleChange = type => {
    this.setState({
      preview: type,
    })
    //this.setState({ preview: type }, () => {
    console.log(this.state.preview, type)
    //})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Card
           style={{
            margin: "10px auto",
           }}
           title={this.state.preview}
           extra={
            <GroupButton
             labels={["edit", "preview"]}
             returnData={this.toggleChange}
            />
           }>
         </Card>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default AddBlogPage
```

here is my child component:

```
class GroupButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      labels: props.labels,
    }
  }

  toggleChange = type => {
    this.props.returnData(type)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button.Group>
          {this.state.labels.map((label, index) => (
            <Button
              value="small"
              onClick={() => {
                this.toggleChange(label)
              }}
            >
              {label}
            </Button>
          ))}
        </Button.Group>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default GroupButton
```

I tried with this way:

```
  toggleChange = type => {
    this.setState({
      preview: type,
    })
    this.setState({ preview: type }, () => {
     console.log(this.state.preview, type)
    })
  }
```

and this way too:

```
  toggleChange = async type => {
    this.setState({
      preview: type,
    })
    await this.setState({ preview: type })
    console.log(this.state.preview, type)
  }
```

in both case I got perfect changes in console.log(), but my title of card is not changing

Comment: *"this.setState() is not updating data immediately"* Correct. [State updates are asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). If you want to do something once the state has been updated, supply the second argument to `setState` (a "completion" callback). But generally, rendering (which React will do) is the only thing you should do in response to setting state. (There are exceptions, though.)